# Making a discord bot and getting 0.name[BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED]: This field is required error

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Main bot file

```
const {
        Client,
        GatewayIntentBits,
        Routes,
        EmbedBuilder,
        ActivityType,
    } = require('discord.js');
    const { token, clientId, guildId } = require('../config.json');
    const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
    const client = new Client({
        intents: [
            GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
            GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
            GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages,
            GatewayIntentBits.GuildBans,
            GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
            GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
        ],
    });
    const { UrlCommand } = require('../Commands/UrlCommand.json');
    
    client.on('ready', (client) => {
        console.log(`${client.user.username}#${client.user.discriminator} running`);
        client.user.setPresence({
            activities: [{ name: 'connections', type: ActivityType.Watching }],
        });
    });
    
    client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
        if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;
    
        if (interaction.commandName === 'url') {
            console.log(`called ${interaction.commandName} command`);
    
            const urlEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
                .setColor('0x0099FF')
                .setTitle('LEPSES')
                .setURL('https://lepses.com')
                .setAuthor({
                    name: 'LEPSES Bot',
                    // TODO: replace icon
                    iconURL:
                        'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/89/Latin_capital_letter_L_with_descender.svg/497px-Latin_capital_letter_L_with_descender.svg.png',
                })
                .setDescription('You choose, we connect!')
                .addFields(
                    // TODO : add more data in the fields
                    { name: 'Regular field title', value: 'Some value here' },
                    { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
                    {
                        name: 'Inline field title',
                        value: 'Some value here',
                        inline: true,
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Inline field title',
                        value: 'Some value here',
                        inline: true,
                    }
                );
    
            await interaction.reply({ embeds: [urlEmbed] });
        }
    
        if (interaction.commandName === 'clear') {
            if (interaction.options.get('amount') >= 5000) {
                interaction.reply('You cannot delete more than 5000 messages');
            } else {
                try {
                    const amount = interaction.options.getInteger('amount');
                    const Channel = interaction.channel;
                    if (amount) {
                        Channel.bulkDelete(amount, true);
                        await interaction.reply(`${amount} messages purged`);
                    } else {
                        Channel.bulkDelete(50, true);
                        await interaction.reply(`50 messages purged`);
                    }
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log(err.message);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    
    const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(token);
    
    async function main() {
        // const commands = [];
        const commands = [UrlCommand];
    
        try {
            console.log(
                `Started refresing application ${commands.length} commands`
            );
            await rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId), {
                body: commands,
            });
            client.login(token);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('ERROR=================================================');
            console.log(error.message);
            console.log('ERROR=================================================');
        }
    }
    
    main();
```

URL Command in json file

```
{
    "name": "url",
    "description": "Visit us now!!"
}
```

Url command was in the main file earlier but now I'm moving older commands to external files to make the code smaller and easier to change in the future. But as soon as the code runs it shows BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED error. It runs normally if I declare commands as an empty array. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the exported command in JavaScript as well. JSON is a storage file type. Try refering to [discord.js](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-handling.html#individual-command-files) command handling guide and see if it helps you.